# Selenium webdriver not responsive after click

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to web outlook of test exchange server. Using selenium webdriver I am able to input the username , password and then click on the sign in button in web outlook. But after clicking there is no response in selenium neither throwing exception.No actions beyond the click will be performed.
But same scenario if I am running with HTTP instead of HTTPS, everything works fine.
Does it has to do something with IE settings? I have unchecked 'Warn about certificate address mismatch *" in Advanced section of Internet Options. This is done to bypass the SSL certificate error.

Answer (score 1):

There may be few reasons.
1)Element may be out of focus. try focusing the element by using sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).

2)There may be a page refresh happening or AJAX call when you are trying to click element. try using implicit wait until ajax call completes.

3)Website which you are trying to automate may be Siebel application(containing Active X Control)